# How to make output of hadoop mapreduce as input of restful api?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, restful-url

Recently I am studying mapreduce, I can use mapreduce to process my data. Now I want to use restful API to show output of mapreduce, but I do not know how to  make output of  hadoop mapreduce as input of restful api? Or how restful api process the output of hadoop mapreduce?
I really needs your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either export the files from HDFS to your local file system, or to read them via the HDFS API.

Comment: Now I store the output in HBase table(stored in HDFS file), when I need the output, I need to get the output from HBase, so I think it costs a little time and is not perfect for app. So I want to make output of mapreduce can act as the input of restfulAPI in time.  Through these days learn, I found that mapreduce coding style is not flexible.   Mapreduce only has the file input and output forms?

Comment: Hive is not a very good fit for an interactive application. Depending on a query, it might take form 30 sec to a minute or two just to go through the motions of setting up Ap/Reduce job(s), even if the amount of data is trivial. If you want to support a REST API that expects responses at lower latencies, you would have to insert another layer between the API and your data.